# I don't know how to fix my update code, vb.net to access database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

[image]
This is the error I get
I don't know how to fix my update code, vb.net to access database I don't understand the error, though the database/connection notifies me it's opened

Comment: `ex.ToString()`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots for errors since it will be difficult after to search on stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

"& My.txtSearchMyID.Text &" ---> '" & My.txtSearchMyID.Text & "'